# How to detect the java class from a generic JAXBElement<? extends >

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, glassfish

I'm working on a WebService built from an existing WSDL, using NetBeans and Glassfish.
NetBeans has created the needed classes from the given WSDL.
The WSDL define some base data types (for example BaseType) and other data types which extend them. (for example ExtType1, ExtType2 ...)
Some of the SOAP functions described in WSDL accept parameters of BaseType type, so it could be possibile to use extended types as parameters, too.

In the web service client, written in PHP, I can invoke a method using a base type parameter:

```
$response = $ws->__soapCall(
    'myFunctionName',
    array('theParameter' => array (
              'BaseTypeField1' => 'some value',
              'BaseTypeField2' => 'some other value'
         )
    ) 
);
```

or using an extended type parameter

```
$response = $ws->__soapCall(
    'myFunctionName',
    array('theParameter' => array (
              'BaseTypeField1' => 'some value',
              'BaseTypeField2' => 'some other value',
              'ExtTypeField1' => 'some value',
              'ExtTypeField2' => 'some other value'
         )
    ) 
);
```

Now in netbeans generated classes I have an object of type JAXBElement<? extends BaseType>, where a BaseType object is expected.

The question is: how can I determine, from within the Java web method call, if the parameter object from the web service client is a BaseType one or one of his extended types (and which of those)?
I have tried to retrieve some class data information for that object, but it always says it's a BaseType, so I cannot know if ExtTypeField1 and ExtTypeField2 are available for sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have something like this `JAXBElement<? extends BaseType> object` you can determine the type of the value as follow:

```
Class<? extends BaseType> klass = object.getValue().getClass();
```

Now from there you can do something based on the object type but this is not always the best way to go. What you will probably want is more something like this:

```
BaseType value = object.getValue();
if (value instanceof ExtType1) {
    ExtType1 field1 = (ExtType1) value;
    // we now know that it's an ExtType1
} else if (value instanceof ExtTypeField2) {
    ExtType2 field2 = (ExtType2) value;
    // we now know that it's an ExtType2
} // etc...
```

Comment: Uhm, I have just tried something like 

    
    Class<? extends BaseType> klass = object.getValue().getClass();
    

but how I can determine if klass is a BaseType or a ExtType1? It always says BaseType...

Comment: Have you read my second proposition? Either way, if your klass says it is `BaseType`, then it is a `BaseType` and not `ExtType1` nor `ExtTypeX` (unless `ExtType1` is a super-type of `BaseType`).

Comment: Okay, it says is a `BaseType`. So it seems, from the PHP web service client side, that calling the web service function with only the `BaseType` fields or even with the `ExtType` fields does not make any difference, at Java side, and I always obtain a `BaseType`...

I don't understand your second approach very well. `ExtTypeField1` and `ExtTypeField2` are members of `ExtType` so how could `value instanceof ExtTypeField1` ever work?

Comment: Sorry, I read too fast. I have edited my answer to make it more like your example. The idea of `instanceof` operator is to know if an object instance is of a given type (either an `interface` or a `class`). If the answer is `true` then you can cast the object instance to the chosen type and use all the public fields and methods of that type.

Comment: Unfortunately `instanceof` always says `value` is a `BaseType`. It seems JAXB always binds to a `BaseType` object, even if, from the PHP side, the function parameter contains members which are of a `ExtType` object.